# Resizing images in Photoshop - Paint style

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixel-art

Microsoft Paint is the worst image editing tool I could ever imagine of, but it has one good thing that still makes me use it over Photoshop: When I enlarge a small, pixelated 16x16 image, it doesn't make it blurry, instead, it enlarges every pixel in the image, so that the image will still look pixelated as it did before, but now it's just bigger.

I know that this by itself might not be the best resizing algorithm and in most situation's, Photoshop's way of doing this proves to be more satisfactory. However, I'm doing some pixel art right now and I need the pixels to still look like squares when I enlarge the image. I would just use Paint, but the problem with Paint is that it doesn't keep transparency.

In a nutshell, the question is: How to enlarge an image in Photoshop without making it blurry, like the way Paint does? In other words, "Enlarge as if I've just zoomed in."

Comment: "Use "Nearest Neighbor" option under "Resample Image" while resizing the image." is the answer. Can someone just post this as an answer? I can't do it until after 8 hours due to lack of reputation :(